# No Access To UserDetailsService in LogoutController When Logged into Grails Application via SAML

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-saml

Using Spring SAML Security, I've enabled our application as a Service Provider.  This works great, I use a custom WickedUserDetails (extended from GrailsUser), and everything populates as it should.

Now I'm trying to implement the global logout for SAML, but even before I can do anything "fancy," I've noticed that when I hit our regular LogoutController, I do not have access to WickedUserDetails.  I just have an anonymous grails user.

This behavior happens when I try to access /logout/index and /logout/special.  It works as expected when I use SlogoutController.

```
class LogoutController {

    def springSecurityService

    /**
    * Index action. Redirects to the Spring security logout uri.
    */
    def index = {
        // Populates with ANONYMOUS GRAILS USER when logged in via SAML
        // but with WickedUserDetails when logged in via the "normal" Spring Security mechanism
        def check = springSecurityService.principal

        redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl // '/j_spring_security_logout'
    }

    def special = {
        // Populates with ANONYMOUS GRAILS USER when logged in via SAML
        // but with WickedUserDetails when logged in via the "normal" Spring Security mechanism
        def check = springSecurityService.principal

        redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl // '/j_spring_security_logout'
    }
}

class SlogoutController {

    def springSecurityService

    def special = {
        // Populates with WickedUserDetails
        def check = springSecurityService.principal

        redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl // '/j_spring_security_logout'
    }

    // Populates with WickedUserDetails
    def index = {
        def check = springSecurityService.principal

        redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl // '/j_spring_security_logout'
    }

}
```

In my Config.groovy, I don't have any special interceptor URLs set up, the only reference I have to the logout URL is:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
    '/login/**'  :      'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL',
    '/logout/**' :      'REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL'
]
```

This is the only reference I have set up in UrlMappings:

```
"/logout/$action?"(controller: "logout")
```

Can someone please explain to me why this behavior happens?  I can come up with a workaround in my app, but I am insanely curious as to what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the issue was my taking shortcuts.  In the authentication provider originally, I was not updating the bespoke token with the SAML credentials

```
Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {

    if (authentication instanceof SAMLAuthenticationToken) {

        def samlToken = super.authenticate(authentication)
        if (samlToken) {
            String username = samlToken.principal
            LightweightContact contact = new LightweightContact(username: username)                         

            contact = contact.findByUsername()

            boolean isContactValid = contactValid(contact, samlToken)

            if (isContactValid) {
                WickedAuthenticationToken wickedToken = MyNormalSpringCustomWickedAuthenticationProvider.getWickedAuthenticationToken(contact)
                // -------- I needed to explicitly set the credentials here -----------------------
                wickedToken.setCredentials(samlToken.credentials)
                return wickedToken
            }
        }
    }

    // the authentication token was not of the correct class
    // or no user was found for it
    return null
}
```